# change textView color using if else condition

Tags: android

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
                R.layout.recentlist,
                new String[] { CAT, DATE, TID, AMO, DEB,CUR,BAL,FEES}, new int[] {
                R.id.textView1,R.id.textView2, R.id.textView3, R.id.textView4,R.id.textView5,R.id.textView7,R.id.textView6,R.id.textView8});

        DEB.setTextColor(Color.RED);



        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

I want to set color to the DEB or textView5.But I am getting this error.

The method setTextColor(int) is undefined for the type String

I have also tried using

```
                   R.id.textView5.setTextColor(Color.RED)
```

But this error came

Cannot invoke setTextColor(int) on the primitive type int

Please help me regarding this.

Comment: you can do this TextView tv = (TextView)findViewByID(R.id.textView5); tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);

Answer (score 2):

As for your seccond attempt, `R.id.textView5` is a reference to your `TextView`. To get the object itself, use `findViewById` method:

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5)).setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

(assuming `R.id.textView5` is indeed an instance of `TextView`).

Comment: I can't do this because it will pick the textView id of the other xml file.This xml layout is for listview only.

Answer (score 1):

you have to create textview object

Try this

```
TextView textView5 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);

textView5.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following code.

```
TextView textView5 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);

textView5.setTextColor(R.color.RED);
```

Comment: I can't do this because it will pick the textView id of the other xml file.This xml layout is for listview only.